# How to Display Multiple text Link On hover Image while the image would also change

Tags: html, css

When i tried to hover on the link, the image  keep flipping, my problem is the image keep flipping continuesly when i hover on the text link

```
/** for flipping the image on hover **/
#image:hover {
background: url(/image/product.jpg);
}

#image {
background: url(/image/greenflip.jpg);
height: 430px;
width: 281px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#link {display:none;}
#image:hover + #link { display:block}
```

Comment: Do you have an example/demo of what is happening?

Comment: Could you test your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ and edit the question with the link to your attempt? It would really help to understand where the problem is.